# python - how to count user has transactions in 1 year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
dt          userid  amt 
6/17/2019       1   200
7/30/2019       1   400
8/17/2019       1   300
4/14/2019       1   140
5/19/2019       1   230
1/7/2019        2   170
2/25/2019       2   450
3/4/2019        2   350
4/17/2019       2   76
5/12/2019       2   900
6/30/2019       2   300
7/20/2019       2   40
8/21/2019       2   60
9/20/2019       2   50
10/9/2019       2   40
11/27/2019      2   70
12/11/2019      2   80
4/9/2019        3   30
10/4/2019       3   20
10/18/2019      3   10


dt            user_id    transaction     not_active
8/17/2019        1          no               9  
12/11/2019       2          yes              5
10/18/2019       3          no               7
```

My data is 1-year in 2019 from January to December. I want to know...

1) count each user has transactions 12 months or not?

```
  yes means a user has transaction 12 month
```

2) when is the latest date?

3) is it active? >> mean how long do users not active, now is May 2020.

```
  user1 last transaction August, and now is May, then 9 months is not active

  user2 last transaction December, and now is May, then 5 months is not active
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
from operator import attrgetter

#convert column to datetimes
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'])
#moth periods
df['per'] = df['dt'].dt.to_period('m')

#get today month period
now = pd.to_datetime('now').to_period('m')

#aggregate maz and number of unique value of month periods
df1 = df.groupby('userid').agg(dt = ('dt','max'),
                              transaction = ('per','nunique')).reset_index()

#set values by condition, eq is for ===
df1['transaction'] = np.where(df1['transaction'].eq(12), 'yes', 'no')
#get difference of months periods
df1['not_active'] = (now - df1['dt'].dt.to_period('m')).apply(attrgetter('n'))
print (df1)
   userid         dt transaction  not_active
0       1 2019-08-17          no           9
1       2 2019-12-11          no           5
2       3 2019-10-18          no           7
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, I have another question. I put it below your answer. Could you help me see how to compute?

Comment: @bee_me - Is possible create new question?

Comment: Question 1: I found some errors that if column "dt" has 12 records per user, it shows "Yes", but it is wrong. I change 8/21/2019   2  60  to  7/21/2019,  it still shows "Yes". Because user 2 has transactions 11 month and 12 records, this need show "No"